# Android:add helvetica neue font in application

Tags: android, fonts

I am making an app in which i have to use helvetica neue font for text but problem is thid that i don't know that how to use helvetica font in android .My question is that do android support helvetica font and it yes then how to use that that font because i was not able to find helvetica font in windows-preference-general-appreance-color and fonts .Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: you'll need to include the respective font file (ttf) in your application.

Comment: Hope you know that Helvetica is free only for personal use.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
place the TTF file in the ./assets directory (create it if it doesn’t exist yet).
```

then in your activity,

```
   1. TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.custom_font);  
   2. Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "<font file name>.ttf");  
   3. txt.setTypeface(font);
```

For more info look at:

[Using Custom Fonts](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/customize-android-fonts/)

[Using Custom fonts on Android](http://techdroid.kbeanie.com/2011/04/using-custom-fonts-on-android.html)

[How to use external fonts in Android](http://www.botskool.com/geeks/how-use-external-fonts-android)

Answer (score 1):

From API Level 26 android support adding custom font directly from the project without creating custom textview or edittext.

Find it out from below link: 
[Fonts in XML](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/fonts-in-xml)